# How do I get the ErrorCode variable value from the response variable after message sending using CURL?

Tags: php, sms, php-curl

After executing CURL I am getting the `$result` variable value as:

```
 {
    "ErrorCode": "000",
    "ErrorMessage": "Success",
    "JobId": "6878b812-766d-48a2-9dae-2b0edf2d84d4",
    "MessageData": [{
        "Number": "919730842844",
        "MessageParts": [{
            "MsgId": "919730842844-64a40d7611f94c03bea1045fdfa9bac5",
            "PartId": 1,
            "Text": "\u0027messagecontentsmstest\u0027"
        }]
    }]
  }
```

Now i need to check for the `ErrorCode == 000`, so how can I get the value of individually `ErrorCode`?

Comment: You need to properly format your question, by putting code and the like in code tags. A question should also show: A minimum working example to reproduce the problem and what you were trying to do!

This question is gonna get closed otherwise

Answer (score 1):

This response received is like JSON.

So I thought to decode it as an json_decode:

$chk = json_decode($result);
echo $chk->ErrorCode;

or we can even try in another way like,

$array = json_decode($result, true);
echo $array['ErrorCode'];